# react on change check if equal to array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, onchange

i have input and array of object
i need when i type it will display the object. "airplaneCompany" is the object property that i need to compare
i was doing only if the input is equal to the "airplaneCompany" it will return it by the filter method
but i need for evrey char it will check it and if the object start with "a" it will show this object

```
  const [txtInp, setTxtInp] = useState("");
  const showFlight = users.filter((user) => {
    return user.airplaneCompany == txtInp;
  });

     {showFlight.map((user, index) => {
        const { id, airplaneCompany, passenger } = user;
        return (
          <div className="flightContainer" key={index}>
            <div>{id}</div>
            <div>{airplaneCompany}</div>
            <div>{passenger}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Patrick answer, but JavaScript has its own [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function you can use.

Also, consider wrapping the filter with the `useMemo` hook to run it only when the input changes and not on every render.

```js
const showFlight = useMemo(() => {
  return users.filter((user) => {
    return user.airplaneCompany == txtInp;
  });
}, [txtInp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your .filter function to check if the airplaneCompany starts with the user input?

Something like

return user.airplaneCompany.indexOf(txtInp) === 0;

Answer (score 0):

just use regex. just place input value like `/^airplaneCompany$/`

```js
const wrongInputText = 'q'
const rightInputText = 'airplaneCompany'

console.log('wrong', 'return value=', /^airplaneCompany$/.test(wrongInputText))

console.log('right', 'return value=',/^airplaneCompany$/.test(rightInputText))
```